# The Domain of this Calculus II Function

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the domain of this function: 
[image]

I thought the domain to be (2, infinity) because (x-2) is 0 when x = 2 and ln(x-2) is undefined when x = 2. However the correct answer is (2, 2 + e) U (2 + e, infinity). What causes a problem when x = 2 + e in this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You say "ln(x- 2) is undefined if x= 2".  That's true since ln(0) is undefined.  But, in fact, ln(y) is also undefined for y< 0.  ln(x- 2) is undefined for x<= 2.   If x= 2+ e then x- 2= e and ln(e)= 1.  So 1- ln(x- 2)= 1- 1= 0.  Then the denominator is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$(1 - \ln (2 + e - 2))^2 = (1 - \ln (e))^2 = (1-1)^2 = 0$$